# How can I get the mobile Version of stackoverflow.com on Evo3D?

Tags: browser, stock-browser

I just got a new phone (HTC Evo 3D / Android 2.3.4) and opened `stackoverflow.com` in the browser.

I noticed I got the desktop version of the website. On my old HTC Desire (Android 2.2.2) I get a mobile version, which is friendlier on the device and probably more lightweight.

What can I do to have the mobile version on the Evo 3D as well?

Comment: Do any other sites "prefer" the desktop version instead of mobile on your Evo?  If so, it could be a setting in the Browser app.

Comment: One option or the time being is to click the "mobile" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answers; it *was* a setting in my browser (*Mobile view* was OFF). Also, the mobile link is a good option. Can you promote your comments to answers? You both deserve votes.

Comment: If you want to just browse through questions and answers try StackDroid from the app store. You cannot post or answer due to API limitations but on the move it serves the purpose, the only real time you have questions to be asked is when you are working with a desktop.

Answer (score 6):

The Stack Exchange sites provide a "Mobile" link in the footer that will give you the mobile layout. It should work regardless of your browser's settings or which browser you happen to be using, so in that sense it's actually a very portable solution.